# Choose intermediate cells automatically in CollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, collections

I want to select **intermediate** cells **automatically**. If I select **start time** and **end time**, like as a **screenshot**, here I **select 01:00** as **start time** and **06:00** as **end time**. And I want to select **automatically** select time **02:00, 03:00, 04:00, 05:00**, it's is as example...

Maybe my client want to select **01:00 as start time** and **21:00** as **end time** accordingly, **automatically** should be selected **all the time**.

I have **three time range**, it's need for me to display **different time** for **working** and for **each range time** i have **three prices**. For example:

**First time and price** made for **morning**.

**Second time and price** made for **day**.

**Third time and price** made for **evening**.

[image]

Can I to do and how to do it? Maybe there are **frameworks** which will help me to do this **quickly**?

My code is here:

```
class BookingViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    var bookingHall: Halls?

    var timeIntervalArray: [String] = []
    var timeIntervalArrayTwo: [String] = []
    var timeIntervalArrayThree: [String] = []
    var selectedTimeIntervalArray: [String] = []

    var bookingAmountOfHallArray: [Int] = []
    var sumOfBookingAmount: Int = 0

    var allArrayTimesAndPrices: [(time: String, price: Int)] = [] // ARRAY FOR COLLECT ALL TIMES AND ALL PRICES

    lazy var timeFormatter: DateFormatter = {

        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
        return formatter

    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        configureSelectedDateAndTime()

        collectionView.allowsMultipleSelection = true 
        // MORNING TIME RANGE
        if let timeRange = generateTimeRange() {

            self.timeIntervalArray = timeRange
            self.collectionView.reloadData()

        } else {
            // Handle error
        }
        // DAY TIME RANGE
        if let timeRangeTwo = generateTimeRangeTwo() {

            self.timeIntervalArrayTwo = timeRangeTwo
            self.collectionView.reloadData()

        } else {
            // Handle error
        }
        // EVENING TIME RANGE
        if let timeRangeThree = generateTimeRangeThree() {

            self.timeIntervalArrayThree = timeRangeThree
            self.collectionView.reloadData()

        } else {
            // Handle error
        }

        if let hall = bookingHall {

            allArrayTimesAndPrices =
                timeIntervalArray.map({ (time: $0, price: hall.price) }) +
            timeIntervalArrayTwo.map({ (time: $0, price: hall.priceSecond) }) +
            timeIntervalArrayThree.map({ (time: $0, price: hall.priceThird) })

        }

    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return allArrayTimesAndPrices.count

    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "timeCell", for: indexPath) as! BookingTimeCell

        cell.timeLabel.text = allArrayTimesAndPrices[indexPath.item].time
        cell.priceLabel.text = "\(allArrayTimesAndPrices[indexPath.item].price) руб."

        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        let selectedCell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)

        selectedIndexesAndBackgroundColor(cell: selectedCell!, indexPath: inde xPath)

    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        let deselectedCell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)

        deselectedIndexesAndBackgroundColor(cell: deselectedCell!, indexPath: indexPath)

    }
    // the selected time
    func selectedIndexesAndBackgroundColor(cell: UICollectionViewCell, indexPath: IndexPath) {

        let timeToAdd = allArrayTimesAndPrices[indexPath.item].time
        selectedTimeIntervalArray.append(timeToAdd)

    }
    // cancelled time
    func deselectedIndexesAndBackgroundColor(cell: UICollectionViewCell, indexPath: IndexPath) {

        let timeToRemove = allArrayTimesAndPrices[indexPath.item].time
        let indexTime = selectedTimeIntervalArray.index(of: timeToRemove)
        selectedTimeIntervalArray.remove(at: indexTime!)

    }
    // MORNING
    func generateTimeRange() -> [String]? {

        var result = [String]()

        if let hall = bookingHall {

            guard var startTime = timeFormatter.date(from: hall.firstStartTimeToIncreasePrice) else { return nil }
            guard let endTime = timeFormatter.date(from: hall.firstEndTimeToIncreasePrice) else { return nil }

            while startTime <= endTime {

                result.append(timeFormatter.string(from: startTime))

                startTime = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .hour, value: 1, to: startTime)!

            }

        }

        return result
    }
    // DAY
    func generateTimeRangeTwo() -> [String]? {

        var result = [String]()

        if let hall = bookingHall {

            guard var startTime = timeFormatter.date(from: hall.secondStartTimeToIncreasePrice) else { return nil }
            guard let endTime = timeFormatter.date(from: hall.secondEndTimeToIncreasePrice) else { return nil }

            while startTime <= endTime {

                result.append(timeFormatter.string(from: startTime))

                startTime = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .hour, value: 1, to: startTime)!

            }

        }

        return result
    }
    // EVENING
    func generateTimeRangeThree() -> [String]? {

        var result = [String]()

        if let hall = bookingHall {

            guard var startTime = timeFormatter.date(from: hall.thirdStartTimeToIncreasePrice) else { return nil }
            guard let endTime = timeFormatter.date(from: hall.thirdEndTimeToIncreasePrice) else { return nil }

            while startTime <= endTime {

                result.append(timeFormatter.string(from: startTime))

                startTime = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .hour, value: 1, to: startTime)!

            }

        }

        return result
    } 
}
```

Comment: All this different arrays are a little bit confusing. Either try to reduce the code in order to only show what you want to know, or provide a link to a runable Xcode demo project which depicts the problem.

Comment: @AndreasOetjen I added comments for my code and a little explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create below global properties:

```
var selectedIndexPath:IndexPath! // store selected indexpath

var arrSelectedIndexPath = [IndexPath]() // array of selected indexpath
```

After then

```
extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return timeArray.count
}

// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: (self.view.frame.size.width - 60) / 7, height: (self.view.frame.size.width - 60) / 7)
}

// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    // dequeue cell
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell

    // assign text to label
    cell.lblTitle.text = self.timeArray[indexPath.item]

    if self.arrSelectedIndexPath.contains(indexPath) {// if arrSelectedIndexPath contain indexpath then change backgrond color of label

        cell.lblTitle.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 81.0/255.0, green: 182.0/255.0, blue: 186.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)

    }else { // else set it to default color white

        cell.lblTitle.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

    }

    // return collection view cell
    return cell
}

// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if self.selectedIndexPath == nil { // if selected indexpath nil then assign first indexpath

        self.selectedIndexPath = indexPath
        self.arrSelectedIndexPath.removeAll() // remove all items from array
        self.collectionView.reloadData() // reload CollectionView

    }else {

        if self.arrSelectedIndexPath.count == 0 { // if arrSelectedIndexPath.count == 0 then

            if self.selectedIndexPath.item < indexPath.item { // check first selected indexpath is smaller then end indexpath

                // fill all intermediate cell
                for i in self.selectedIndexPath.item...indexPath.item {
                    self.arrSelectedIndexPath.append(NSIndexPath(item: i, section: 0) as IndexPath)
                }

                // reload collection view and update background color
                self.collectionView.reloadData()

                // reset first selected indexpath
                self.selectedIndexPath = nil

            }else { // else select first selected indexpath

                self.selectedIndexPath = indexPath

            }

        }else { // else remove all items from

            self.arrSelectedIndexPath.removeAll()
            self.collectionView.reloadData()
            self.selectedIndexPath = indexPath

        }

    }
}

// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

}

Hope it works for you!

Comment: Thanks, this is what I need. :)

Comment: excuse me, but can you tell me how i can highlight first selected item?

Comment: @Dima, you can add first selected indexpath in the array and reload collection view.

Comment: sorry for the stupid question, but where to write it?

Comment: @Dima Check below link: I have uploaded view controller file here https://drive.google.com/open?id=10zGy5YZaMEaQRZjdj2746oH1AlX2jpox

Comment: Happy Coding (y)

Answer (score 1):

Have two global objects for indexPaths

```
var selectedRowOne:IndexPath? <br>
var selectedRowTwo:Indexpath?
```

After that in `didSelectItemAt`

```
   if selectedRowOne == nil {
        // Start of range is empty !!

        selectedRowOne = indexPath;
        // Logic for select the row
    } else if selectedRowTwo == nil {
        // End of range is empty
        selectedRowTwo = indexPath

        var indexPathToBeSelected :[IndexPath] = []

        for i in selectedRowOne!.row  ..< selectedRowTwo!.row {
            indexPathToBeSelected.append(IndexPath(item: i, section: 0))
        }

        // Select indexPathToBeSelected logic
    }
```

As your code is too confusing to I can't write code for one case . so  Now You have to manage one case where where both `selectedRowOne` and `selectedRowTwo` is selected and user tap on any of cell.

Then you have to check if selected  `indexpath.row <selectedRowOne.row` then    `selectedRowOne =  indexpath`

Secondly `else if`   `indexpath.row > selectedRowOne.row && indexpath.row < selectedRowTwo.row` then   `selectedRowOne =  indexpath`

and at last condition

`else if`   `indexpath.row > selectedRowTwo.row`
Then   `selectedRowTwo =  indexpath`

And after all apply cell selection logic for range between  `selectedRowOne` and  `selectedRowTwo`

you need to take care of de select cell also if two cells are selected and if I Deselect first or second you need to manage `selectedRowOne` and  `selectedRowTwo` properly

Hope it is helpful to you

Answer (score 0):

create one property to store selectedIndexPath
`var selectedItem: IndexPath?`,
then assign it's value for first selected item.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    guard let selectedItem = selectedItem else{
        selectedItem = indexPath
        return
    }

    //loop for selecting items between current selected item and previous selected item.
    for i in selectedItem.row...indexPath.row {
         let selectedCell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: IndexPath(row: i, section: indexPath.section))
         selectedIndexesAndBackgroundColor(cell: selectedCell!, indexPath: inde xPath)
    }        

}
```

and do the same in `didDeSelectItemAt` for deselecting items accordingly.